# Can I update a records value using an addition?

Tags: sql, sqlite, math, counter, addition

How can I add a number to an INTEGER column?

Like
`UPDATE tbl SET col +? WHERE id = ?`

where the first `?` is the number which I want to add

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
UPDATE tbl 
SET col =col+1 
WHERE id = ?
```